# PDO execution in php wont return any row but there are some if I execute the same query in the database

Tags: mysql, pdo, row

I have a really annoying problem, I have thins interface that creates a query and execute it in the database via PDO. Most of the time it will work just fine but sometimes the query will return 0 rows while executed via the PDO, nonetheless if I execute the very same query directly in the database (MySQL) I'll get some results.

My Code:

```
        $connect = $this->get('db');
        $q = $connect->prepare($chain1);
        $q->execute();
        $query = $q->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In the chain I have concatenated the query and the same query is stored in a separate file, when I get that query and execute it in the database I get rows. Whereas in the code I've wrote I get none.

I've already tried changing the PDO code for fetching the rows and looking in PDO manuals to find some insights but I can't find any, please help as I'm starting to drive mad.. lol.

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 14.04 (server and client same behavior).
Versions:
    php5   5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6
    php5-mysql  5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6
    php5-odbc   5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6

many thanks for any idea you could give me.

Comment: By default, the [PDO error mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) is silent—so you must manually check for error conditions.  It's often a good idea to set another error mode during development.

Comment: do you have this typo in your code? `$q->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` just remove slash there?

Comment: @Alex: That's not a typo—it indicates that the `PDO` class is defined in [global space](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).

Comment: @Alex yeap eggyal is right.

Comment: @eggyal Hi, thanks for the idea.. I've enabled the error mode and I get no error... still doesn't show any record.. regards

Comment: Do you actually do anything with `$query`?